# Getting a conflicting types error when trying to include this data type in another header file I'm unsure why

Tags: symbolicc++

```
#ifndef CALLER_H_
#define CALLER_H_

#include "stdlib.h"
#include "cardCell.h"



#endif /* CALLER_H_ */


_______________________________________________________________


typedef struct
{
    int row;
    int col;
    char letter;
    char digit;
    bool matched;
} cardCellContent;
```

Getting a conflicting types error when trying to include this data type in another header file I'm unsure why.

Comment: Your `#include "stdlib.h" ` should be `#include <stdlib.h>`. Need more info for better help.

Comment: and if you truly are using c++ and not c it would be `#include <cstdlib>`

Comment: here is a list of standard c++ header files : [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header)